# Why is partial used to add attributes to functions

Tags: python, python-decorators

I read [this](https://martinheinz.dev/blog/24) article the other day, and I don't understand why `partial` is used in the section "Logging Decorators":

```
def attach_wrapper(obj, func=None):  # Helper function that attaches function as attribute of an object
    if func is None:
        return partial(attach_wrapper, obj)
    setattr(obj, func.__name__, func)
    return func
```

`attach_wrapper` is unsed to set some attributes on a function that wraps another function:

```
@attach_wrapper(wrapper)  # Attaches "set_level" to "wrapper" as attribute
def set_level(new_level):  # Function that allows us to set log level
    nonlocal level
    level = new_level
```

Why can't these attributes be directly set on `wrapper` with `setattr`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you instrument `attach_wrapper` you can see that it accounts for its `func` argument being `None`.

```
def attach_wrapper(obj, func=None):  # Helper function that attaches function as attribute of an object
    if func is None:
        print(f'obj is {obj.__name__} - func is',func)
        return partial(attach_wrapper, obj)
    print(f'a_w:obj is {obj.__name__} - func is {func.__name__}')
    setattr(obj, func.__name__, func)
    return func
```

Then

```
@log(logging.WARN, "example-param")
def somefunc(args):
    return args
```

Results in

```
>>>
obj is somefunc - func is None
a_w:obj is somefunc - func is set_level
obj is somefunc - func is None
a_w:obj is somefunc - func is set_message
>>>
```

---

`attach_wrapper` is called twice. The first time its `func` is `None` and it returns a partial function `attach_wrapper` with its first argument `obj` *set to* `some_func`. Then the partial is called (all parts of the decorator mechanism) with the function being decorated.

`attach_wrapper's` `obj` looks like `some_func` but it is actually `some_func` *wrapped with* `wrapper` - it looks and feels the same because that is what [@wraps](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) was made for.

---

Here is a little more detail adding `inspect.stack` to the *instrumentation*.

```
import inspect

def attach_wrapper(obj, func=None):  # Helper function that attaches function as attribute of an object
    print("called from: ", inspect.stack()[1].code_context[0].strip())
    print("\tby function ", inspect.stack()[1].function)
    if func is None:
        print(f'\tobj is {obj.__name__}, func is {func}\n')
        return partial(attach_wrapper, obj)
    print(f'\tobj is {obj.__name__}, func is {func.__name__}\n')
    setattr(obj, func.__name__, func)
    return func
```

Which produces

```
>>>
called from:  @attach_wrapper(wrapper)  # Attaches "set_level" to "wrapper" as attribute
    by function  decorate
    obj is somefunc, func is None

called from:  def set_level(new_level):  # Function that allows us to set log level
    by function  decorate
    obj is somefunc, func is set_level

called from:  @attach_wrapper(wrapper)  # Attaches "set_message" to "wrapper" as attribute
    by function  decorate
    obj is somefunc, func is None

called from:  def set_message(new_message):  # Function that allows us to set message
    by function  decorate
    obj is somefunc, func is set_message

>>>
```

---

There are some better detailed explanations around. If and when I find one I'll update.

Answer (score 4):

It's used so that if the `attach_wrapper` function is called without a function to wrap, it will return something that you can then call with other functions to attach more than one to the targeted object. For example, if you had three functions `f`, `g`, and `h`, and an object `foo`, you could create an "attacher" with `attach_to_foo = attach_wrapper(foo)` and then use it with `attach_to_foo(f)`, `attach_to_foo(g)`, and `attach_to_foo(h)` to end up with `foo.f`, `foo.g`, and `foo.h`.